# facebook style user profile URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi everyone i need help about htaccess. I am trying to make a facebook style profile url like : `https://www.example.com/azzo`

So the `user_profile.php` is in the pages folder. Now user profile link is this `http://www.example.com/pages/user_profile?username=azzo` So i want to cut the pages file name from the url. What should i do to use my url like facebook (`https://www.example.com/azzo`) .

I am using the following htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^group/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/group.php?group_username=$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What should i do to change the url like this:

`http://www.example.com/pages/user_profile?username=azzo`

to this

`https://www.example.com/azzo`

I have tryed the following rule:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)([\w-]+)/?$ pages/user_profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

after the

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but i get blank page.

Comment: Fine. And your question is _what_ ? What is wrong with what you implemented? Or is this meant to be a guessing game?

Comment: @arkascha I have edited my question. It is not be a guessing game, cerious question here.

Comment: You get a blank page? That means you do get a response, not an error message? Check your http servers error log file, that most likely is where the issues php bubbles out get logged to. What does it say?

Comment: @arkascha I am in localhost where is the error log file ?

Comment: Depends on the configuration of your http server. Typically something like `/var/lib/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: @arkascha there are no saved any errors after year of 2014 :S

Comment: That means it is the wrong file, since also service restarts are logged there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171828/discussion-between-arkascha-and-azzo).

Comment: If you want `https://www.example.com/azzo` to be handled by `http://www.example.com/pages/user_profile?username=azzo` then your last rule i.e. `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [L,QSA]` will never be invoked since new proposed rule will have same pattern as `.+?` only. Why not have user URLs with a prefix such as `https://www.example.com/u/azzo`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes i changed that like your comment and working fine now. Thank you

Comment: @anubhava I need a mini help can you help me please dear ?

Comment: @anubhava Hi Dear. You know i am using your htaccess answer in my website. But i am getting the error from profile rewriterule. Can you please check my question for me please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504460/internal-server-error-when-url-have-twice-file-name