# Internal Server Error when url have twice file name

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error when i wrote the twice file name from the url.

I am using the following RewriteRule for the user Profile url:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]  
RewriteRule ^profile/(followers|friends|saved|stories)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The Rules working working fine with this link:

```
https://www.thewebsiteurl.com/profile/username
```

But if i wrote the file name twice like this

```
https://www.thewebsiteurl.com/profile/profile/username
```

then i am getting the 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there any answer here to fix this problem ?

Here is my Full of my HTACCESS codes:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.websiteurl.com/sources/not-found.php          
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]  
RewriteRule ^profile/(followers|friends|saved|stories)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]    


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L] 


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A http status 500 does not really say much, since it does not show the actual error message. For obvious reasons: that is valuable information not meant for outside people. You need to take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the actual issue is.

Comment: The issue is not immediately those rewriting rules. They may be part of the issue, but there has to be another factor, probably your application logic which you did not tell us about. Little we can say here.

Comment: @arkascha I have already checked error log file but there is empty. Not have any report :(

Comment: Your error log file definitely cannot be empty. It _always_ contains entries. Could it be that you are looking at the wrong file? Or that you disabled logging?

Comment: @arkascha I am using arvixe webhosting, i didn't do anything i think it is automatically disabled.

Comment: @arkascha I have added full my htaccess code maybe it will more help to fined the problem.

Comment: For `/profile/` you immediately terminate the rewriting, so the request is (most likely) handled by the directory index logic, so (again most likely) the `/index.php` file. Why it generates a http status 500 is, as already said, not the fault of those rewriting rules.

Comment: It could also be that there is _no_ directory index rule defined, which could also lead to such issue if the requests do not get rewritten, as in your case.

Comment: @arkascha If i turn on `-MultiViews` like `+MultiViews` then it redirect me `not-found.php` page but then profile url didn't work on that time.

Comment: @arkascha I think the problem is this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules appear to fine though I have seen in some web servers that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` doesn't work properly due to file name resolution issues.

Can you try changing that rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes your answer is working fine. I have also try it before, but it will happend another problem. When i click logout button, then if the files are in the subfolder it is redirecting me main domain. Like for example: if i the files are in script folder then if i click `localhost:8888/script/logou` it will redirecting me `localhost:8888/`

Comment: the logout.php is redirecting me `localhost:888/script/index.php` with this code: https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VOoWGy . How can i check the output network it is redirecting me the page is changing.

Comment: That just doesn't look correct Why should there be an external redirect in php code when you have so many rewrite rules to handle routing.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean why i use `$base_url` in the php code ? If yes, i just try if that is problem or not. Normalize there is not have `$base_url`

Comment: Rather than redirecting to `localhost:888/script/index.php` your php code in `logout.php` can just redirect to `localhost:888/`

Comment: Dear i found another solution, this rule is fixed also my problem. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`